# A function that finds the kth smallest integer in array A (unsorted), of size n

Tags: c, algorithm

```
int kth_smallest_number(int A[], int n, int k){
    /*kth smallest number is smaller than pr equal to n-k numbers in A*/
    int smaller_than_count;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        /*Check whether the number A[i] satisfies
        the condition*/
        smaller_than_count = 0;
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            if(A[i]<=A[j]){
                smaller_than_count++;
            }
        }
        if(smaller_than_count == n-k){
            return A[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I just wanted to know if this solution is right, I am not worried about efficiency right now just correctness.

Comment: i have the feeling that your code didn't come out the way you wrote it, is that correct? For more help see [markdown help](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/formatting#code)

Comment: Before I go any futher, this is known as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Comment: The code in the question had leading tabs, instead of the four spaces required by Markdown. I've taken the liberty of reindenting the code in the question (which we normally don't do).

Answer (score 4):

**The compiler is your friend**

Activate all warnings and you'll get pretty good hints :

```
selection.c: In function ‘kth_smallest_number’:
selection.c:17:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

**Test your code**

Here's what I have written to test your code :

```
int A[] = {4,4,56,78,54,6512,21,8,7,2,321,87,78,54,2,21,5,4,321,456,5,4,35,5,4,1,67,8,1,54,4,654,7,6,54,321,7,32,4,21,54,7};
int n = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
for (int k=0; k<n; k++)
{
    printf("%d %d\n",k,kth_smallest_number(A,n,k));
}
```

I'd expect the returned value to be sorted and it's clearly not the case here. Thus, I expect something to be wrong.

Playing with other inputs : `int A[] = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0};` , `int A[] = {10,9,8,7,6,5,5,4,3,2,1,0};`, it seems like your solution does not handle properly duplicated value.

**A matter of style**

The indentation looks weird on your question.

You should try to declare your local variable in the smallest possible scope. Among other things, you can define your loop indices in the loop syntax in you use the C99 mode (`-std=c99`).

Once rewritten (but still wrong), your code looks like :

```
int kth_smallest_number(int A[], int n, int k){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        /*Check whether the number A[i] satisfies
          the condition*/
        int smaller_than_count = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            if(A[i]<=A[j]){
                smaller_than_count++;
            }
        }
        if(smaller_than_count == n-k){
            return A[i];
        }
    }
}
```

---

Edit :

**An attempt to correctness**

Here what I have written , it seems to work fine but I won't promise anything.

```
int kth_smallest_number(int A[], int n, int k){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        /*Check whether the number A[i] satisfies the condition*/
        int ai = A[i];
        int smaller_than_count = 0;
        int bigger_than_count = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            int aj = A[j];
            if (ai < aj) {
                smaller_than_count++;
                if (smaller_than_count >= n-k) break; // Optimisation
            } else if (ai > aj) {
                bigger_than_count++;
                if (bigger_than_count > k) break; // Optimisation
            }
        }
        if(smaller_than_count < n-k && bigger_than_count <= k){
            return ai;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can handle the element duplicates without altering the array?

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a potential solution.